# Does re-baking of physics give exactly the same result?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, baking

I was wondering if re-baking of physics (smoke, fire, clothing) would give exactly the same result ? Or is this a sort of "random" process ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it shouldn't.**

If you *do* want a different random look you need to change the [random seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed).  The exact location to set the seed varies a little depending on which simulation you are talking about, but just look for a setting called *Seed*.

Comment: Don't you mean it *should* give the same result unless you adjust the random seed?

Comment: @PGmath I did understand your message, but I guess Mentalist has a point ;)